# I need to remove all <h#> series tags using single template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Is this possible to remove the h# series number using the XSL

Input XML using as:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h2>
            <img src="https://admin.com" />
          </h2>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>
            <img src="https://admin.com" />
          </h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>
            <img src="https://admin.com" />
          </h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

XSL I used as:

```
<xsl:template match="table/tbody/tr/td/h2[img]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table/tbody/tr/td/h3[img]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table/tbody/tr/td/h4[img]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

As like in all input lot of h# will possible in the table. Is this possible to write the single template to remove all h1 h2 h3....... h-series from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several [pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#pattern-syntax)s in the sample template e.g. `<xsl:template match="table/tbody/tr/td/h2[img] | table/tbody/tr/td/h3[img] | table/tbody/tr/td/h4[img]"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`.

I wouldn't suggest to use a regular expression, if you want to shorten the pattern then perhaps doing

```
<xsl:template match="table/tbody/tr/td/*[(self::h1 | self::h2 | self::h3 | self::h4 | self::h5 | self::h6) and img]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi @Martin. Thanks. Is this possible to using any regular expression for that h-series numbers to remove. Please suggest??

Comment: I am not sure using a regular expression in a pattern to match different element names is a good idea, you can of course try e.g. `*[matches(name(), '^h(1|2|3|4|5|6)$')]` but for clarity y efficiency it might be better to spell out the element names in a step of a pattern.